# Android JNI: Fail to link to static library (Undefined Reference)

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface, static-libraries, undefined-reference

I'm new to Android JNI and I need to use the static library (librwl.a) in my project. But I'm now having error message undefined reference. Can anyone please kindly advice what's the problem? Thanks in advance

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := staticlibrwl
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuild/librwl.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jrwl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := rwl.cpp

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := staticlibrwl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

rwl.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>

#include "include/librwl.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ms_android_pos_NativeRWL_Format
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
    return Format();
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ms_android_pos_NativeRWL_InitActionList
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
    return InitActionList();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int Format();
extern int InitActionList();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Error Message:

```
D:\Project\android-ndk-r10\ndk-build.cmd all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-17 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: jrwl <= rwl.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libjrwl.so
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o: in function Java_ms_android_pos_NativeRWL_Format:jni/rwl.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to 'Format'
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o: in function Java_ms_android_pos_NativeRWL_InitActionList:jni/rwl.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'InitActionList'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libjrwl.so] Error 1
```

Error Message after using ndk-build V=1 -B (Edit on 6-Aug-2014):

```
D:\Project\android-ndk-r10\ndk-build.cmd V=1 -B all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-17 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
del /f/q .\libs\armeabi\gdbserver     >NUL 2>NUL
del /f/q .\libs\armeabi\gdb.setup     >NUL 2>NUL
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
copy /b/y "D:\Project\android-ndk-r10\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver\gdbserver" ".\libs\armeabi\gdbserver" > NUL
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi" > ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe "directory D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/include jni/include D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/system/include" >> ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: jrwl <= rwl.cpp
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -O0 -UNDEBUG -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Ijni/include -ID:/Project/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -Ijni/include -Ijni -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security      -ID:/Project/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/rwl.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o 
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
del /f/q obj\local\armeabi\libstdc++.a >NUL 2>NUL
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar crsD ./obj/local/armeabi/libstdc++.a 
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libjrwl.so
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libjrwl.so -shared --sysroot=D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-17/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o -Wl,--whole-archive jni/prebuild/librwl.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive ./obj/local/armeabi/libstdc++.a -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -LD:/Project/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib -L./prebuild -lstdc++ -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi/libjrwl.so
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o: in function Java_ms_android_pos_NativeRWL_Format:jni/rwl.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to 'Format'
D:/Project/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/jrwl/rwl.o: in function Java_ms_android_pos_NativeRWL_InitActionList:jni/rwl.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'InitActionList'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libjrwl.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you provide more verbose output; particularly with how the linker is being called?  I suspect LOCAL_SRC_FILES is not where a static library should go... its more of an object file, In practice it should be passed to the linker with -L./prebuild/ -lrwl.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the comment. I searched on the internet and followed some examples (http://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/use-of-prebuild-static-library-compiled-with-android-toolchain/) that's why I put my static library to LOCAL_SRC_FILES as shown in my code. Can you elaborate more on how to pass the static library to the linker with -L./prebuild/ -lrwl ? I'm not sure how to do this in eclipse. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Alex I have tried to run "ndk-build V=-1 -B" and edited the error message shown. Is there any hints showing what's my problem is? Thank you